# Значение ошибки EOFError: Добавлено больше `input()` чем требовалось

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

Выполняю задание с курсов ЛЭТИ:
Напишите функцию, которая принимает на вход список целых чисел, возвращает 2 переменных: длину этого списка, и разницу между максимальным и минимальным значением.
Мой код:

```
def chek_list(L):
    result_1 = len(L)
    result_2 = max(L_1) - min(L_1)
    return result_1, result_2


L = input().strip().split()
L_1 = [int(i) for i in L]
print(chek_list(L))
```

При запуске в pycharm все работает, но при проверке на сайте выдаёт ошибку "EOFError: Добавлено больше `input()` чем требовалось".[

Comment: Очень интересно узнать какие данные вы вводите.

Comment: Так же покажите скриншот куда вы вводите ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
def check_list( l : list ):
    return len(l), max(l) - min(l)

n = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(check_list(n))
```

Попробуйте заливать на ресурс так же в таких вариантах:

```
def check_list( l : list ):
    return len(l), max(l) - min(l)
check_list(L)
```

Или

```
def check_list(l):
    return len(l), max(l) - min(l)
```

Comment: замените chek_list(L) на chek_list(n)

Comment: Выдаёт ту же ошибку.

Comment: @АлександрИванов Каким образом? Какая версия python и какие данные вы вводите?

Comment: В pycharm я сам ввожу список например ввод 1 2 3. Результат (3, 2). А на ресурсе ЛЭТИ ничего вводить (кроме самого кода) не надо, он сам подставляет данные при тестировании кода.

Comment: @АлександрИванов Попробуйте залить на *ЛЭТИ* только функцию передавая ей L и её вызов( без print() ) или только функцию.

Comment: Как уже писал выше список [1,2,3] через пробелы .

Comment: @АлександрИванов Я изменил свой ответ, перечитайте его.

Comment: Ну так отправь им просто функцию

Answer (score 0):

Вот так надо более кратко излагать Вашу идею:

```
def chek_list(L) -> tuple:
    return len(L), max(L) - min(L)

L = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(chek_list(L))
```

Comment: Простите, не объясните к чему у вас используется `strip()`?

Comment: Желание Автора - сейчас уберу:)

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось сайт ЛЭТИ подставляет значения переменных прямо в функцию и никаких input в программе действительно не нужно. Ниже я привел код который проходит проверку на сайте.

```
listing='2 4 6 56'
L =listing.strip().split()
L_1 = [int(i) for i in L]

def check_list(L_1):
    result_1=len(L_1)
    result_2=max(L_1)-min(L_1)
    return result_1,result_2

print(check_list(L_1))
```